# Why don’t most RISC ISAs write integer MULH/MUL or DIV/REM to two general-purpose registers?

Tags: arm, cpu, alu, mips, arithmetic-division

Most hardware multiplication and division algorithms can compute the high and low words of a product of two integers, or both the quotient and remainder of the division of two integers, at the same time.  In major RISC ISAs, there are many different approaches to integer multiplication and division.  (In this post, I am only considering integer and not floating-point math.)

- Most early RISC designs do not have such instructions at all.
- MIPS I has multiply instructions that return the double-word result in a pair of special-purpose registers, $HI:$LO, as well as divide instructions that return the quotient in $LO and the remainder in $HI.  Moving the contents of either $HI or $LO into a general-purpose register is another instruction.
- SPARC V8 and higher will store the low word of a multiplication or the quotient of a division into a specified register, but stores the high word of multiplication or the remainder of division in a special-purpose register, %y.
- Most RISC architectures of the ’90s, including POWER, Alpha, and PA-RISC, have separate instructions to put *either* the high word or the low word of a multiplication in any general-purpose register, and to put a quotient in any general-purpose register, but not to compute a remainder at all; to get the remainder, you would calculate *c* = *a*/*b*, then find *d* = *a* - *b* × *c*.
- The ARM A32 ISA does have two of the instructions I’m interested in, `SMULL` and `UMULL`, which were introduced in v3M.  These store the high and the low word of the product of two 32-bit integers in different 32-bit registers. It has many other variant multiplication instructions as well.  It does not, however, compute the remainder of a division.
- ARM A64 redefines `SMULL` and `UMULL` to store the 64-bit product of two 32-bit integers in a 64-bit register.  It has no 64-bit multiply instruction, *per se*.  To multiply, you do a multiply-add that adds the zero register.  There is integer division, but no integer modulus.
- The RISC-V ISA with the M extension has several variants of `MULH`, `MUL`, `DIV` and `REM`, but the *RISC-V Instruction Set Manual* recommends that when a `MULH` is followed by a `MUL` with the same source operands, or a `DIV` by a `REM` with the same source operands, microarchitectures can fuse these operations into a single operation instead of performing two separate ones.

It’s definitely possible to compute the full result of a multiplication, or division and remainder, at the same time.  Several RISC ISAs have one instruction to do so!  In theory, if you want only one result, you could set the destination of the other to the zero register.  Why, then, does no RISC ISA that I looked at have an instruction to store both the quotient and remainder in separate general-purpose registers, and why does the one ISA I found that does this for the high and low words of a product, ARM A32, drop it in the next major revision?

I am particularly interested in why the early RISC chips of the mid-’80s made this design choice.  SPARC V8 didn’t have an instruction format with two source and two destination registers and possibly didn’t want to complicate its decoder with another format.  MIPS I: cutting corners to fit more complex instructions into a classic RISC pipeline?

But I am also wondering why modern RISC architectures have moved away from it.  I’m guessing ARM A64 does it that way because fixed-precision multiply-add is useful for multimedia decoding, with less relative overhead the more bits you multiply, and, once you have that, it makes sense to reuse the circuits for multiplication (just add 0). But the RISC-V documentation suggests that the core should have a single operation that computes both results, so why not, in a RISC design, expose that in the ISA?

Have there been any published papers discussing this issue?  Or have the designers of these architectures ever explained their rationale for it?

Comment: Why? Why not? Just because something is possible doesn't mean it's desirable from any number of points of view, economic, culture, die area, SPARC tried that so we're going to do something different, our compiler wouldn't like it, our compiler guy that suggested that has just left so let's not do it ... Do you know how complicated office politics gets when you need to make a more or less arbitrary customer-facing decision?

Comment: Was it that arbitrary, then? Or was there a particular reason it was unfeasible? Or not a useful optimization?

Comment: Quite a good question, actually. You might look at the adsp-2100 series for its special div instruction. That could be used, but it was only good for one bit at a time. I've written many a routine to perform division for FP as well as integer use and I always can provide both as easily as just one of them. Same time, same cycles. So yes, a good question.

Comment: Just as a side note, since it seems you've been researching. Decades back, Bipolar Integrated Technologies developed the first fully combinatorial FP divide IC. They are long gone now.

Comment: @jonk Huh. The forerunner of RISC, the IBM 801, had a divide step instruction too. https://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/www.bitsavers.org/pdf/ibm/system801/System_801_Principles_of_Operation_Jan76.pdf (42)

Comment: I wasn't saying anything novel about the adsp-2100. Just calling attention to it. I'll look at the the docs you mention when I get a moment and see how it compares. I do believe the BIT FP div was a first on its scale, though. And not relocated since, perhaps. Would be interested to be wrong, though.

Comment: Just thoughts... Multiply and division use punishingly deep logic compared to other CPU operations and that makes them often the slowest by far to implement. So I can reason why a CPU design decouples its MUL and DIV away from the core, to get the speed of the rest of instruction execution up. Makes me wonder if the remainders come out of a deeper logic stage than the DIV result. Since it can be calculated easily enough from the DIV result, it might make sense. Dunno if that was obvious to you anyway or if it helps :-)

Comment: this is clearly worth closing due to primarily opinion based.  There is no actual answer you would have to seek out each of the design teams for each architecture.  Perhaps as mentioned you understand 1) you are VERY lucky to have a hardware divide at all if you have one 2) likewise for multiply but it is not as painful and more often implemented than divide.  for many clock cycle operation they take minimal amounts of logic, but as you approach single clock cycle they can begin to swamp the whole of the rest of the design

Comment: this is why you see on some arm cores for example an option to use a single cycle multiply or a many cycle multiply.  save on chip real estate.  not sure about the rest of your question it is obvious that an Nbits = Nbits * Nbits multiply is somewhat useless and wasteful, now an Nbit = Nbit/Nbit is more useful.  If your complaint is that you cant pick all the registers well that is just too bad, there are likely obvious reasons for that but are likely architecture specific.  and if you are in a single clock operation solution then perhaps computing the modulo separately has a valid tradeoff.

Comment: @old_timer If anybody’s wondering why this question is suddenly getting attention again, seven months after it was originally closed, that’s because another user edited it to add “a clear call-to-arms question.”  And then it started getting more comments and votes. So I figured, I might as well expand on that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally, the business requirements for processor designs are directed to meet either **synthetic benchmarks** or **real-world application workloads**. Features that don't address either of those are harder to sell, and therefore more likely to be left out.

During the 80s, the Dhrystone benchmark was very popular. Usually this would be presented in a high-level language, usually C. Dhrystone does not include any remainder operations! So designers targeting a high Dhrystone score might leave out remainder operation to shave a few picoseconds off the cycle time.

Most high-level languages have separate arithmetic operators for quotient and remainder, very few provide standardised operations to give both from a single operation (partly because C and FORTRAN don't have native tuples!). Until recently compilers haven't been great at the kind of optimisation-spotting that would enable them to fold two operations into one instruction.

If we look at the kind of arithmetic-heavy work that processors *have* been optimised for, it tends not to care about remainders. The big examples are FFT and matrix multiplication for linear algebra. Those are why processors tend to have multiply-accumulate instructions and SIMD instructions.

Comment: Thank you! I was partly motivated by solving a problem with a fast algorithm that involved a lot of `%` operations. The C standard library does have `div()` and `ldiv()`, which return two-member structs and are intended to take advantage of hardware that finds both the quotient and remainder at once. Compilers can now usually do this optimization automatically, those instructions are (as noted) less common, and `/` and `%` have been as well-specified as `div()` and `ldiv()` since C99. There’s not really an advantage to using them any more, and I wonder how much code ever did.

Comment: Since you bring up FFT, that raises the question: was the Good-Thomas prime-factor FFT algorithm relatively unpopular because `mod` was slow, and was `mod` slow because algorithms like Good-Thomas weren’t considered important?

Comment: div/mod has always been slower than multiplication, which I think must have driven that choice. Many architectures have single-cycle multiply and slower division; some of the microcontrollers have multiply but no divide at all.

Comment: On the multiplication side it is noticeable that until C99 added the "long long" type there was no way to write a 32x32->64 multiply on a 32-bit ILP32 system in standard C and there is still no way to write a 64x64->128 multiply in standard C.